# Angular $http.get automatically convert int to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My API endpoint returns this JSON and I can verify it in the browser

```
[1, 4686, 4691, 4696, 4]
```

My problem is when I run $http.get in Angular like this

```
return $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
//do some stuff here
});
```

My response becomes this

```
["1", "4686", "4691", "4696", "4"]
```

I could overcome this problem by running a loop and parseInt each element but I want to avoid using too many loops in my script. What is the cause of this and how to fix it?

PS: I have cleared all cache and tried with Chrome Incognito but still not helpful.

Comment: `$http` does not convert anything. If array of numbers is sent that's what you should get in the response data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a quick mapping to convert all the strings to numbers:

```
return $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
    $scope.numbers = response.map(Number);
});
```

If you want to quickly verify this, c/p this into your console in chrome:

`["1", "4686", "4691", "4696", "4"].map(Number)`

Comment: should be `response.data.map(Number);`